# How to pass selected date from AJAX calendar Control into stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, oracle, stored-procedures

I have written an insert stored procedure in oracle 11g. I am able to pass all the values except date value which I am getting from an Ajax calendar control in asp.net page

I have textbox with this control, when user select the date from calendar control it will display in that textbox. How to pass the textbox value into the stored procedure?

Written in C# for asp.net application

Some of ways I tried

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_WARRANTYENDDATE", OracleDbType.Date));
command.Parameters["p_WARRANTYENDDATE"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(AMCStartDateTextBox.Text).ToShortDateString();
```

even tried to pass it as string

```
 string AD = Convert.ToDateTime(AMCStartDateTextBox.Text).ToShortDateString();
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_AMCSTARTDATE", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
 command.Parameters["p_AMCSTARTDATE"].Value = AD;
```

Getting unterminated string constant error

Comment: so whats the problem you are facing, are you getting any error? if so please post exception message..

Comment: @SunilGudivada Getting unterminated string constant error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this below code & it works !!!!!!

```
string AMCStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(AMCStartDateTextBox.Text).ToShortDateString();
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_AMCSTARTDATE", OracleDbType.Date));
command.Parameters["p_AMCSTARTDATE"].Value = AMCStartDate;
```